# why isn't our sharpoint site search box working well?

Tags: search, search-results, metadata

Our search results suck (not ranking) just good old site searching.

Is this related to metadata?

Comment: Could you please define 'suck' as it is a rather ambiguous in this context.  Also, what version of search are you using and which version and edition of SharePoint are you using (i.e. 2010 Foundation, 2007 MOSS, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

Metadata helps, the more info you can explain about an item, the more flexibility you'll have when searching. But there's a balance, asking too much from users and they won't enter it.

Check out my blog post, http://davidlozzi.com/2012/12/06/my-users-dont-like-sharepoint-because-they-cant-find-what-theyre-looking-for-part-1/, where I focus on methods to improve search for your users.

HTH